# How to set dependency of an external deb file in the deb file?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, debian

I need to create a deb file with just set two other deb files as dependency so that both of them will install before this deb file.

If it is a package available in apt repo, I can directly mention as -d like I kept for nano and git below. But it is not supporting to set external deb files.

So, I kept in --before-install to a shell script. But getting below error.

preinst file:

```
echo "---pre Installing----"
wget https://github.com/uday1kiran/python_deb_create/raw/testdeb2/tmp/agentxw_1.036-1_amd64.deb
apt install -y ./agentxw_1.036-1_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/uday1kiran/python_deb_create/raw/testdeb2/tmp/xvision_0.97-1_amd64.deb
apt install -y ./xvision_0.97-1_amd64.deb
echo "--pre install completed--"
```

And my command:

```
fpm -s empty -t deb -n test -v 1.3 -d git -d nano --after-install --before-install ./preinst
```

[image: error with apt]
Please suggest how to set that external deb file as dependency. If not with fpm, any other tool that supports that.

Comment: Whilst in installing you can't install other packages. The idea of a deb package is that it references libraries, not debs. You might create a deb that creates an "install app" for your stuff. But that  app has to be called after you've installed it. So it makes no sense to me

Comment: Add a script to your deb, user has to run it after installing your deb package.

Comment: This looks very similar to the question you asked yesterday: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1439695/how-to-include-external-deb-files-as-dependencies. The difference is unclear.